Cartoon with flying couch?
I remember having a cartoon video around 1993/4 with episodes of which I believe a young girl and boy who had an old couch that turned into a magic golden couch with wings and flew them into magic lands and gave them all different types of adventure? I can't think of the name and can't find it anywhere. It's not "Tiny Planets" it's an actual cartoon, not animation. 
I vaguely remember one episode of them seeing a wizard and at the end he have them each an egg with a prizes inside. 
The other episode I remember on the video is one where they go to a bizarre land with sheep in it and the sheep is selling peas to them ! Bizarre I know ! 
And another one is where they have landed in the sea and an octopus sings to them ! 
Please help me remember and discover the name. 

 
The Adventures Of The Wishing Chair
The episodes were part of the BBC animated series ''Enid Blyton's Enchanted Lands''. Here's a synopsis for the book:

Mollie and Peter, searching for a birthday present for their mother,
  find a mysterious antiques shop which appears to be run by fairy folk.
  There, they find a magic wishing chair with the power to grow wings
  and fly. After the chair rescues them from the shop, and gets them
  home, they decide to keep the chair in their playhouse. On their first
  flight, they rescue a pixie called Chinky from a giant. The pixie
  comes to live in their playroom, and the remainder of the book
  concerns the adventures of the children, as the chair takes them, and
  Chinky to various magical places.They also get into trouble due to
  some invisible paint, and a boy who makes faces, and cannot unmake
  them. But they also have some good adventures like going to
  Greatheart, the magician's party or going to Grabbit Gnomes. The
  children have a most pleasant time with the chair, with some near
  misses! ~ From Wikipedia

Watch the programme intro, plus you should be able to catch most of the episodes here. Just to get things rolling, here's the singing octopus :-)

Thankyou so much this is exactly what i was looking for. Not seen this seen i was 3 years old! :)
